# MUI Selection of an Object (MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, selection

I want to set a MUI Selection for a list of objects ([{name: "", id: "" }]).

The selection list should show the name and id of the object and the selected value should only show the name. The most important part is that I want to return the selected object with id and name in the onChange-handler.

I basically already got the solution what I want to have, but I can't get rid of the "You have provided an out-of-range value..." warnings. Is there a way to solve this or should I just ignore/disable this warnings?

A codesandbox-example of the component is found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-banzai-pkhnkb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you set a value on the MenuItem to a full object, while you pass a value into Select to be just a string. Change your MenuItem to this:

```
<MenuItem key={el.id} value={el.id}>
```

and the Select to this:

```
 <Select
          value={entityForm.entity.id}
```

And you will need to update your handle form code as well, but that would deal with that warning.

**EDIT** updated answer to use id rather than name

Comment: If I change the value to el.name I only return a [el.name] in my handler function and not the object with the id

Comment: Use the ids instead of the name in that case. You are right, ids are better to work with. But you will need to change your Select as well to get the id as a value rather than the naem

Comment: okay, I got it. I basically return the Id and render with the id the name as the selected part. With this I won't get any warning.